# SQL Transactions: TSQL vs VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, t-sql, transactions

we're tracking down a nasty timeout bug in one of our applications.

I wanted to know what (if any) differences there are to using the SQL Transaction within the application versus written into the stored procedure using TSQL statement.  We would need to restructure the stored procs and vb code to get this to work and I'm not sure it would be worth the effort at this time.

```
Public Sub RetrieveTData(ByVal cID As String, ByVal cnn As SqlConnection) As Boolean

    Dim sqlTran As SqlTransaction
    cnn.Open()
    sqlTran = cnn.BeginTransaction

    Try
        If Not DataAlreadyTransferred(cID) Then

            Dim Command As New SqlCommand("usp_BigNasty_CopyDataFromDB1toDB2")
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Command.Transaction = sqlTran
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cID", cID)
            Command.Connection = cnn

            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlTran.Commit()
        Endif

    Catch ex As Exception
        sqlTran.Rollback()
        Throw
    Finally
        cnn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

We aren't certain whether the timeout is occurring in `DataAlreadyTransferred()` or `usp_BigNasty_CopyDataFromDB1toDB2` due to how the try/catch is written.  We can restructure this code, but will take a week or so to get it to production (no errors occur on test/dev today)

DB1 - permanent storage, used by other applications as well
DB2 - working set, used only by Web App

`DataAlreadyTransferred(cID)` first checks to see if DB2 has any copies of the records, if DB2 does and those records are clean it deletes them (data could have changed in DB1 and we want the most up-to-date version).  If DB2's data is dirty it is left alone and no data is deleted.

`usp_BigNasty_CopyDataFromDB1toDB2` copies rows from approximately 20-30 different tables and copies over the perm copies from DB1 into DB2, essentially creating a working set from which the Web App can access

We are aware this is inefficient and are examining ways to improve it, just haven't had time yet...

I believe by having the transactions in the app code it's locking many more tables than is really needed.  If we move them to the stored procs, less tables will be locked at one time thus improving our chances of removing deadlock conditions/timeout issues we're seeing today.  Just not sure on this..

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation we've discovered that many of the tables involved had no indexes on them.  After creating the recommended indexes for the queries involved in this process our timeouts issue has seemed to go away (for now).

I'm still going to be looking into optimizing this entire process, as it's still pretty slow for the amount of data it's churning through...

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction is open for longer than needed with round trips and multiple calls.

I'd suggest a single stored proc that tests *and* cleans *and* writes = one atomic call to the server.

I'd also consider replication to keep the data live in near real time, or even mirroring too if DB2 contains a lot of DB1. Let the DB engine do it?

Comment: We're currently looking at moving the app code into a single stored proc which might end up being the final solution here, and in that case I'd also want the transaction in that procedure instead of in the app code..  Also DB2 is a much smaller subset of DB1, or I would have pushed for something like replication in the beginning as you suggest.